# How do we manage and control configuration files in Sqoop (1)?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, sqoop2, sqoop

I would like to manage and see the effects of each of the parameters of the configuration file for Sqoop (1). How do we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop provides two ways to manage the application specific configurations. 
We can use `-D <property=value>`

```
sqoop export \
-D sqoop.export.statements.per.transaction=10 \
--connect jdbc:mysql://mysql.example.com/sqoop \
--username sqoop \
--password sqoop \
--table cities \
--export-dir cities
```

or put all the properties in a configuration file and give this file to `-conf <configuration file>`

**FYI**: You must supply the generic arguments `-conf`, `-D`, and so on after the tool name but **before** any tool-specific arguments (such as `--connect`).

Ref: https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_using_generic_and_specific_arguments

Comment: Thanks Sai!!. In my cluster, all my configuration been commented and but, I would like to know more significance of each configuration parameter in the file and I would like to override them later. Can you please share me from that context as well ?